# About C++ ofstream synchronization

Tags: c++, file-io, synchronization, codeblocks, ofstream

Before asking question, I'll explain about this situation.

There are two computers.(call them A and B)
A only writes a file.
and B only reads the file(which A wrote)

The problem is synchronization.

If A tries to write a file while B is reading the file
A doesn't write anything.

So, I want to make A wait if any user(especially B) is accessing to the file.

Is there any useful function to check file is being used?

(I'm using Code-Blocks, not Visual Studio)

Comment: Where is the file stored?

Comment: it is stored in computer A, and B access to file like open("\\111.222.333.444\file.txt")

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standard mechanism who checks if a file is in use by another thread / process / computer.

I think you will have to handle it by yourself, that is define an *access policy* to your file, e.g. create another `~stragename` file as a handle to synch A and B.